# MoSql and YAML parsing: Invalid ordered hash entry

Tags: sql, mongodb, postgresql, yaml

I'm using MoSql 0.4.3 with the following YAML file:

```
MyDb:
  Names:
    :meta:
      :table: Names
      :extra_proprs: true
    :columns:
     - _id: INTEGER
     - Name:
     :source: Name
     :type: TEXT
```

However I receive the following error:

```
ERROR MoSQL: Error parsing collection map `test.yaml':
ERROR MoSQL: Invalid ordered hash entry {"Name"=>{:source=>"Name", :type=>"TEXT"}}
```

Yet I followed the documentation. How can I fix it?

Documentation:

https://github.com/stripe/mosql/pull/37/files?diff=split

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your YAML input has errors. The key `:source` cannot have the same indentation as the sequence element indicator `-`, it has to align with the first key in the mapping `Name` (and so does `:type`):

```
MyDb:
  Names:
    :meta:
      :table: Names
      :extra_proprs: true
    :columns:
     - _id: INTEGER
     - Name:
       :source: Name
       :type: TEXT
```

just like in the documentation example the key `:source` is aligned with `author_name'.